# what are the Common roll angle and roll rate limits for civil flights?

Tags: flight-controls, attitude, roll

I'm currently doing simulations for eVTOL type of vehicles and for the purpose of controlling the attitude, I'd like to know the common limits for roll and roll rates (more important) that are in place for civil flights. I'm interested both for airplanes and helicopters even though I do prefer information for rotary vehicles.

I've spent a few hours already searching through the web but for some reason, I'm not able to find literal values in documents such as ICAO annexes etc. 
So it would be really helpful for me to know at least the approximate values. I appreciate any answer in advance. Thanks

**UPDATE with respect to comments:**
I am interested in upper boundary, i.e. what rate should not the vehicle exceed. I imagine that there is some at least recommendation that aircraft of a particular type should not exceed this rate, otherwise the passengers can spill their coffee, get sick etc. So it could be also partially dependent on the current wind situation, gusts and so on.

In terms of particular regulatory office, it doesn't really matter as this information should just give some overview of possible values because right now I really dont have any clue.

Comment: Welcome to the site. The limitations should be covered in the certification regulations. If you're fine with USA certification (easily accessible), let us know, also what category is the plane and the envisioned passenger capacity? Add this info to the question as it might help.

Comment: Are you looking for lower or upper limits (e.g. the aircraft must be able to achieve a roll (rate) of at least XXX, or the aircraft shall not have are roll (rate) exceeding YYY)?

Comment: This question is really broad. Aerobatic aircraft are civil one, and they clearly don't have the same limits as an AN-225 fully loaded or a jet airliner full of passengers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum roll rate is documented in [14 CFR 23.157](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CFR-2013-title14-vol1/pdf/CFR-2013-title14-vol1.pdf) (pre Amdt 64), which is used as an [accepted means of compliance](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_23_2010-1.pdf) for the current 14 CFR 23.2135.

As far as I know, there is no regulatory requirement on maximum roll rate. For large transport aircraft, the design target at maximum roll authority is typically around 20 deg/s to 30 deg/s. For example, A320 has a roll rate limit of [15 deg/s](http://www.smartcockpit.com/docs/A320_Flight_Deck_and_Systems_Briefing_For_Pilots.pdf) at maximum lateral input in Normal Law, while A220 has a roll rate limit of [20 deg/s](https://www.flightglobal.com/engines/flight-test-we-put-bombardiers-cseries-through-its-paces/122236.article) in Normal Mode.

There is no regulatory requirement on maximum roll angle. For reference, the A320 has a maximum commandable roll angle of [67 deg](http://www.smartcockpit.com/docs/A320_Flight_Deck_and_Systems_Briefing_For_Pilots.pdf) in Normal Law, while the A220 has a limit of [80 deg](https://www.flightglobal.com/engines/flight-test-we-put-bombardiers-cseries-through-its-paces/122236.article) in Normal Mode. The autopilot disconnect bank angles would be much lower than these.

Comment: Wow, so informative! Thank you a lot for the links as well :)